# How to fork Etherscan block explorer?

Tags: blockchain, etherscan, quorum, explorers

I'm using a blockchain with quorum and I would like to use a block explorer like Etherscan. Is the Etherscan an open-source project? I've seen a lot of explorers that are similar, how can I get one for my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those explorers all use the Explorer-as-a-Service service from Etherscan. You can find more information about it here: https://etherscan.io/eaas

Answer (score 1):

You should consider either Epirus Free or Blockscout block explorers.
Etherscan EaaS is costly.